# Android :: BaseActivity bind Service for all extends Activity

Tags: android

I have an idea to bind service for one time in BaseActivity and use in every Activity by extends it.

Requirement are activity can call service methods and method also call activity too.

Is it possible to do that??

**NOTE**

I can do by binding in each activity only.

I had implement navigation drawer by baseactivity and it work that why I ask is it possible for service?

Answer (score 0):

If you Bind Service from BaseActivity and use in every Activity by extends it then it will bind every time in your every activity, Because methods of base activity calls before activity methods which extends it, in same sequence.

Comment: then it won't different? because every activity was bind in onStart() and unbind in onStop();